# Parsing unformatted log file and exporting it into CSV

Tags: powershell

I have tried couple of things, didn't tried using regex bcoz I am not good with this. The log file looks exactly like this.

```
timestamp :   2018121
streams   : Total    :  579   461   0   0   24     80   0    
ABC : 630                                           
A-1 : 98       
B-2 : 87      
C-3 : 0   
timestamp : 2018127    
stream : Total : 476   372   0   0   20   74   0    10    0  
ABC : 511  
B-2 : 77  
C-3 : 0  
D-4: 86  
timestamp : 2018128  
stream : Total : 76   37   0   0   20   74   0    10    0  
ABC : 517  
A-1 : 74  
C-3 : 9  
D-4 : 18
```

I am trying to export in csv in a transpose manner. For streams I just want to export only the first value.

```
timestamp  streams      ABC      A-1      B-2   C-3  D-4
2018121      579        630        98     87    0    NULL
2018127      476        511      NULL     77    0    186
2018128       76        517        74     NULL  9    18
```

Comment: unable to paste the output I am looking for.

Comment: You should post it as code: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) .... and you should post the code you tried as well, please.  ;-)

Comment: @BijoDev: Try giving the powershell script also what you have tried. So that we can understand the logic.

Comment: ... have something for you ....  ;-)  [Creating Rows to Columns](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/creating-rows-to-columns/#post-138282)

Comment: @Olaf: + 1 from my side. It can go as an answer if you give a sample code with this above data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think you have to perform your proper logic code because your file was soo tipycal  i have work around 10 minutes you have this result it's small code snapp

i have done some change in input because you have in line streams and in other stream ... and in line ' ' and in other '   ' ? soo i think you have a issues in your log generator.

Input :

```
timestamp :   2018121
streams   : Total    :  579   461   0   0   24     80   0    
ABC : 630                                           
A-1 : 98       
B-2 : 87      
C-3 : 0   
timestamp : 2018127    
stream : Total : 476   372   0   0   20   74   0    10    0  
ABC : 511  
B-2 : 77  
C-3 : 0  
D-4: 86  
timestamp : 2018128  
stream : Total : 76   37   0   0   20   74   0    10    0  
ABC : 517  
A-1 : 74  
C-3 : 9  
D-4 : 18
```

Some Code :

```
$fileContent = Get-Content "C:\Temp\logTest.log"

$resultTab = @();

$beginIdentifierRows = "timestamp".ToLower();

for($i = 0; $i -lt $fileContent.Length; $i++){
    if($fileContent[$i].ToLower().StartsWith($beginIdentifierRows)){
        #Read all rows value strams to D-4 or other
        $A1 = "NULL";
        $B2 = "NULL";
        $C3 = "NULL";
        $D4 = "NULL";
        $streams= "NULL";
        $ABC = "NULL";
        $timestamp = $fileContent[$i].Split(":")[1];
        # Write-Host $fileContent[$i];
        $jj = 0;
        for($j = $i + 1; $j -lt ($i + 6); $j++){
            $lineContentJ = $fileContent[$j].Replace("  "," ").Replace("  "," ").Replace("  "," ").Replace("  "," ").Replace("  "," ");
            # $lineContentJ
            switch -Wildcard ($lineContentJ) { 
                "ABC *"{
                    # streams todo
                    $ABC = $lineContentJ.Split(":")[1];
                    break;
                }
                "stream*"{
                    # streams todo
                    $streams = $lineContentJ.Split(":")[2].Split(" ")[1];
                    break;
                }
                "A-1 *"{
                    # A-1 todo
                    $A1 = $lineContentJ.Split(":")[1];
                    break;
                }
                "B-2 *"{
                    # B-2 todo
                    $B2 = $lineContentJ.Split(":")[1];
                    break;
                }
                "C-3 *"{
                    # C-3 todo
                    $C3 = $lineContentJ.Split(":")[1];
                    break;
                }
                "D-4 *"{
                    # D-4 todo
                    $D4 = $lineContentJ.Split(":")[1];
                    break;
                }
            }$jj = $j;
        }
        $i=$jj;

        $array_name = [pscustomobject]@{timestamp = $timestamp; streams = $streams; ABC = $ABC; "A-1" = $A1; "B-2"=$B2; "C-3" = $C3; "D-4"=$D4} 

        $resultTab += $array_name;
    }
    #else {
        #Do nothing
    #}
}

$resultTab | ft;
```

RESULT :

```
timestamp    streams ABC    A-1  B-2  C-3 D-4 
---------    ------- ---    ---  ---  --- --- 
 2018121     579      630    98   87   0  NULL
 2018127     476      511   NULL  77   0   86 
 2018128     76       517    74  NULL  9   18
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it really work the way I was expecting.

Comment: glad to help you.

Comment: can you please help me why this code was added in this 
$lineContentJ = $fileContent[$j].Replace("  "," ").Replace("  "," ").Replace("  "," ").Replace("  "," ").Replace("  "," ");

Comment: @BijoDev because you have soo multiple space between string and values in your file

Comment: @BijoDev it’s replace double space by simple space

Comment: @pascalsanchez  - you could even shorten this pretty much when you use the `-replace` operator instead of the `[STRING].Replace()` method like this  `-replace '\s+',' '`

Comment: @BijoDev - I'd recommend for you to urgently start to learn the basics of Powershell. It's beyond the scope of any forum to teach you step by step how to use Powershell and how to write scripts. Most of the knowledge you need to accomplish what you asked for you would have learned in the first lessions of any book or tutorial or course.

Comment: @BijoDev this script it’s just example i haven’t time for work on best propose i have take some minutes in time for sharing you this way after that you have all powershell website and book to find the best way todo what you want.